# passing this.id to another function returns null error

Tags: javascript

I am trying to pass an ID with a function to another function. The console then informs me that there is a `TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null`. The javascript file is appended at the end and I also tried adding the code into a self executing function, but that didn't solve the problem.

Basically I would like to an `addEventListener` to the sub-category divs (buttons) and they should pass their value to another function.

The error is pointing at this line `let mainCategory = document.getElementById(recived_value).parentNode.firstChild(this.id);` so `recived_value` is *null*.

Any help would be welcome. Thank you.

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="main-category" id="box">
      Boxes
   </div>
   <div class="sub-category" id="b_small">
      Small Boxes
   </div>
   <div class="sub-category" id="b_medium">
      Medium Boxes
   </div>
   <div class="sub-category" id="b_large">
      Large Boxes
   </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var subCategoryClass = document.querySelectorAll(".sub-category");
var subCategoryArray = Array.from(subCategoryClass);

for ( let i = 0; i < subCategoryArray.length; i++ ){
   subCategoryArray[i].addEventListener("click", PassValue(this.id));
}

function PassValue(recived_value){
   let subCategory = recived_value;
   let mainCategory = document.getElementById(recived_value).parentNode.firstChild(this.id);
   TwoArgFunc(mainCategory, subCategory);
}
```

Comment: replace `PassValue(this.id)` by `() => PassValue(this.id)`

Comment: could you please answer with a non-lambda function. I still haven't got my head around them. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were a couple of problems. I described them below in // comments.

Edit: Based on your comment, I changed to a normal function definition.

```js
var subCategoryClass = document.querySelectorAll(".sub-category");
var subCategoryArray = Array.from(subCategoryClass);

for ( let i = 0; i < subCategoryArray.length; i++ ){
   subCategoryArray[i].addEventListener("click", function(ev) { PassValue(ev.target.id)} ); // need a function here, not just a statement
}

function PassValue(recived_value){
   console.log(recived_value);
   let subCategory = recived_value;
   let mainCategory = document.getElementById(recived_value).parentNode.firstElementChild.id; // use firstElementChild because firstChild is a newline text node
   console.log(mainCategory);
//   TwoArgFunc(mainCategory, subCategory);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="main-category" id="box">
      Boxes
   </div>
   <div class="sub-category" id="b_small">
      Small Boxes
   </div>
   <div class="sub-category" id="b_medium">
      Medium Boxes
   </div>
   <div class="sub-category" id="b_large">
      Large Boxes
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @WeAreDoomed compare your code again. When you "Run code snippet" in my answer above, it clearly shows the correct ID.

Comment: True. I just wanted to reply that I see your code running just fine in the example. I checked my code again, but I still get the `typeError`...

Comment: Solved. I had a slightly differenet structure in the HTML, That's why it didn't work. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Hey. Could you also add the code for lambda function? I think I could more easily grasp the concept if I could compare it to an example I understand. Thank you.

Comment: How about I refer you to some good [reading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), specifically the "Comparing traditional functions to arrow functions" section.

Comment: Heh. Thank you. Already skimmed it a few days ago. Will need to take some time to look at it more in depth.

Answer (score 0):

Above `PassValue` function put:

```
var that = this;
```

And then in your `PassValue` function pass `that.id`:

```
... .firstChild(that.id);
```

Comment: Thank you for answering but this doesn't solve the `TypeError: --- is null` problem